# find a cyclic path with a certain node with a certain weight

Tags: java, algorithm, graph-theory

I am trying to build a navigation app. Im trying to think of an algorithm to find a cyclic path that includes a certain node and sums up to a certain weight. 
the input for the algorithm would be a node and a weight.

Example: algo(a,30) - the algorithm wil return a path that can start from node A and finish in Node A and the total sum of it is 30.

extra info: for all w:weights w>0, the graph is directional (as streets are).

thanks ahead
Gal

Comment: Are there any restrictions on the path? Should it pass any node/edge only once or multiple times?

Answer (score 1):

This problem is stronger ( more difficult) than the  [Hamiltonian Cycle Problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hamiltonian_path).  Because if we already have a solution for this problem `algo(a,b)`, for any Hamiltonian Cycle Problem ***P*** we can design a new graph with  weight=1 for edges in ***P*** and 0 for edges not, then use `algo(1,n)` to find a Hamiltonian Cycle, in which `n` is number of nodes in the graph.  So we have a NP-complete problem here.

For applications with small `n`, a brute-force search with certain "pruning" should work fast enough.

Comment: Actually - they are both NP-Complete as I see it, making them *equally* hard.

Comment: you just showed a reduction from The problem i described to hamilton cycle problem. it doesnt say anything about our problem.
if we show a reduction a<=b we can only say tha b is "stroger as a". its doesnt say anything about a

Comment: @amit thanks man, i'm trying to prove the reduction from the other direction

Comment: @Gal I think it's a reduction from hamilton cycle problem to your problem.

Comment: @lavin: The reduction is guaranteed, since the problem is definetly in NP (given a solution, it is easy to validate it is correct), and there is a reduction from each problem in NP to Hamiltonian Path (Definition of being NP-Hard).

Answer (score 1):

The general problem is NP-Hard, and reduceable from the [longest path problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Longest_path_problem), and thus is [NP-Hard](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NP-hard), and there is no known polynomial solution to this problem (and the general assumption is such a solution does not exist).

The longest path problem is: Given a graph `G` with weight function `w`, and a pair of vertices `u`,`v` - find the longest path from `u` to `v`.

**Proof:**

Assuming there is a polynomial algorithm to your problem - one can build an algorithm to longest path problem, with binary search (exponentially increase the wanted weight, until there is no solution, and then - binary search). Each step is polynomial, and there are `O(log|PATH|)` steps. Since `log|PATH|` is polynomial in the input (assuming simple pathes), the algorithm is polynomial.

It is also closely related to [Hamiltonian Path Problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hamiltonian_path) and [Traveling Salesman Problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Travelling_salesman_problem)

Comment: I think algo(a,b) gives the answer which the sum of weight is exactly equal to b. In that case, the binary search for the longest path will not work.

Comment: Consider the case that there's only ONE circle in the graph, and the sum of weights of the edges in that circle is K. There's no way to find K with binary search using algo(a,b), since algo(a,b) will give the same result for both b>K and b<K, which is NULL. And algo(a,b) will return a path only when b=K. How can a binary search works on this case?

Comment: @lavin: Assuming the problem has polynomial solution, if I remember correctly - the *optimization problem* also has polynomial solution, and using the optimization algorithm, you can repeat the process.